# Get current feature name/description in Ruby Cucumber 2.4?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, legacy

I am trying to get the current feature name or description when running tests. This is done in a Before hook, like this `name = scenario.feature.name` or `name = scenario.feature.description`. However it seems that `feature` was removed even from legacy API sometime back, and I can't find the new way of grabbing the feature information. Is it still possible to get the current feature name or description or any other information about the feature in the Cucumber 2.4 (Ruby gem)?

[This](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/1.3.18/Cucumber/Ast/Feature) is no longer in Cucumber gem 2.4.0.

Comment: Did you try? Does it give an error?

Comment: Yes, the attribute does not exist anymore. I want to know if there is a replacement in the updated Cucumber for Ruby..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what error does it return?

Comment: undefined method `feature' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: So, the scenario is nil. What about if you replace scenario.feature by just feature?

Comment: You'll be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1863564) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1863564). While they're not directly Ruby-related, most of the answers are abstract enough to apply here.

Comment: I know if has an issue with a null pointer, I want to know where the feature part of scenario has been moved.

Comment: @Tyler, please show a minimal hook and feature that exhibit the behaviour you mention. Like that we should be able to spot the bug.

Comment: it looks there is no method named "name" in http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/RunningTestCase/Scenario. where is the "name" method defined?

Answer (score 3):

The hooks now pass the scenario object to their blocks as an argument:

```
Before do |scenario|
  puts scenario.feature.name
  puts scenario.name
end
```

This works with `cucumber 2.4.0` and its dependency `cucumber-core 1.5.0`.
I verified it with both `Before` and `After` hooks; `BeforeStep` and `AfterStep` hooks work differently.

Note that `secenario.feature` is a [`Cucumber::Core::Ast::Feature`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber-core/1.5.0/Cucumber/Core/Ast/Feature) (no longer [`Cucumber::Ast::Feature`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/1.3.18/Cucumber/Ast/Feature); the core now lives in its own gem).

Comment: What version is that in? This is how I am doing it right now, and feature is no longer part of scenario.

Comment: undefined method `feature' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: Definitely works on my machine ;) I added a bit more info to the answer.

Comment: When you do this are you referencing the cucumber gem, or cucumber core gem?

Comment: Tried feature = Cucumber::Core::Ast::Feature, and then getting name and description but the same error occurred.

Comment: I got it working with just scenario name, and feature name now. I want to be able set certain variables based off of if the scenario is Cucumber::Core::Ast::Scenario or Cucumber::Core::Ast::ExamplesTable::Row. Using a switch statement based on scenario to see which it is.

Comment: Ah, so that is what you were trying to do. Glad to hear you got it working. Please consider sharing your solution by adding your own answer to the question. I am curious, and other might be interested in the solutions as well.

Comment: I just used the way you provided to get the name. I am unable to get the scenario or feature description though. Was that changed (using scenario.description, and it doesn't exist)?

Comment: It looks like when running the above code it is scenario from http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/RunningTestCase/Scenario , and not AST. This is why getting things like description is having issues. Is there way change this?

Answer (score 0):

In Cucumber `9.1.0` the before hook doesn't actually yield a scenario object, it yields a `Cucumber::RunningTestCase` that wraps a `Cucumber::Core::Test::Case`. We can use that to parse the scenario description using the `AstLookup` as follows:

```
Before do |test_case|
  puts test_case.name
  puts scenario(test_case).description
end

def scenario(test_case)
  # Cucumber doesn't provide direct access to the scenario so this hack is necessary
  cucumber_config = ObjectSpace.each_object(Cucumber::Configuration).first
  ast = Cucumber::Formatter::AstLookup.new(cucumber_config)
  ast.scenario_source(test_case).scenario
end
```